# Replace a string if a particular substring exists?

Tags: string, macos, shell

I would like to replace a string if and only if a string exists in that line. This should be performed across all files in a folder.

```
1. This is My String.
2. Get This string as input.
```

In the above two strings if 'String' is present, replace ***`My`*** with ***`your`***.

Like output should be

```
1. This is your String.
2. Get This string as input.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed '/String/ s/My/YOUR/g' input
```

OR

```
awk '/String/{gsub(/My/,"YOUR")}1' input
```

Comment: The output should even reflect in the file. I want to change across all files in a folder.

Comment: use `sed -i` option or check if you `awk` have in-pace replacement.